# How to #define __forceinline inline?

Tags: gcc, mingw, inline, redefinition

I have some Microsoft code (XLCALL.CPP) which I am trying to compile with CodeBlocks/MinGW.
At this line I get a compile time error:

```
__forceinline void FetchExcel12EntryPt(void)
```

This is the error message I get:

> XLCALL.CPP|36|error: expected constructor, destructor, or type
>   conversion before 'void'

This error is expected, because __forceinline is a Microsoft specific addition to the language, not recognized by GCC.

So, to get things compile, I try to add thiese defines in CodeBlocks (Project Build Options/Compiler Settings/#defines):

```
#define __forceinline inline
#define __forceinline
```

However I still get the same error.

If in the dialog I do not specify the #define preprocessor command (i.e.: `__forceinline inline`), this is what I get:

> XLCALL.CPP|36|error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant

Is there a way to compile such a piece of code, *without using* Visual C++?

Comment: It seems that this is the syntax:
`__forceinline=inline`

Answer (score 12):

The syntax is `__forceinline=inline`, as you've noted in the comments, because these settings get turned into [`-D` options to GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.2/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#index-D-883).

Note that `inline` is a strong hint to GCC that the function should be inlined, but does not guarantee it.  The GCC equivalent of `__forceinline` is the [`always_inline` attribute](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.2/gcc/Function-Attributes.html#index-g_t_0040code_007balways_005finline_007d-function-attribute-2405) - e.g. this code:

```
#define __forceinline __attribute__((always_inline))
```

or equivalently this setting:

```
__forceinline="__attribute__((always_inline))"
```

(But this might well be unnecessary: if there was some particularly good reason for *forcing* this function to be inlined when compiling with MSVC, that reason may well not be valid when using a completely different compiler!)

Comment: Though it's a correct answer to the original question, one may note that using __attribute(always_inline) may litter you with compiler warnings like "warning: always_inline function might not be inlinable [-Wattributes]"

Comment: @Yogurt You might want to use `#define __forceinline inline __attribute__((always_inline))` in order to remove those warnings.